# Error with Mapping array React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api

I'm creating a list of things but it gives me the same error the whole time.
that the .map function won't work on my Variable so can you guys help me out.

It's made in Typescript React.
I was trying to get this to work for a hole week and still can't find the problem
I even tried rewriting the hole system but still didn't work so this is my last hope.

**Error**

```
react-dom.development.js?e444:25163 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at _default (CloudServersContainer.tsx?a799:46)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js?e444:16240)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js?e444:18774)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js?e444:20136)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js?e444:337)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js?e444:386)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js?e444:441)
    at beginWork$$1 (react-dom.development.js?e444:25737)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?e444:24664)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js?e444:24637)
```

**The Json that I get when I do Eggs.data**

Link to the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKC0Y.png

**The Code:**

```
import React, { componentDidMount, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import PageContentBlock from '@/components/elements/PageContentBlock';
import Button from '@/components/elements/Button';
import Input from '@/components/elements/Input';
import InputSpinner from '@/components/elements/InputSpinner';
import tw from 'twin.macro';
import useSWR from 'swr';
import TitledGreyBox from '@/components/elements/TitledGreyBox';
import { Textarea } from '@/components/elements/Input';

export default () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    interface EggsPlace {
        Egg: String;
        run(arg: any): void;
    }

    const [Eggs, setEggs] = useState<EggsPlace>([]);

    const getEggs = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('/api/client/cloudservers/getoptions');
        if (response.status !== 400) {
            const content = await response.json();
            const data = content;
            setEggs({ data });
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getEggs();
    }, []);

    if (typeof Eggs.data !== 'undefined') {
        console.log(Eggs.data[0]);
    }



    return (
        <PageContentBlock title={'Options'} showFlashKey={'options'}>
            <h1>Server Types:</h1>
            <div css={tw`w-full grid grid-flow-col grid-rows-2 grid-cols-3 gap-4`}>
                {
                    Eggs.data !== 'undefined' ?
                        Eggs.data.map(item => (
                            console.log(item)
                        ))
                        :
                        <p>loading</p>
                }
            </div>
            <TitledGreyBox title="Configuration" css={tw`flex-wrap md:flex-no-wrap`}>
                <div css={tw`w-full grid grid-flow-col grid-rows-2 grid-cols-2 gap-4`}>
                    <div css={tw`w-full col-span-2`}>
                        <InputSpinner visible={loading}>
                            <Input
                                readOnly={false}
                                name={"Name"}
                                placeholder={"Name Server"}
                            />
                        </InputSpinner>
                    </div>
                    <InputSpinner visible={loading}>
                        <Input
                            readOnly={false}
                            name={"Memory"}
                            placeholder={"Memory"}
                        />
                    </InputSpinner>
                    <InputSpinner visible={loading}>
                        <Input
                            readOnly={false}
                            name={"Disk"}
                            placeholder={"Disk"}
                        />
                    </InputSpinner>
                </div>
                <div css={tw`mt-4 w-full`}>
                    <Textarea
                        placeholder={'Description'}
                    />
                </div>
            </TitledGreyBox>
            <Button css={tw`mt-4`} color="primary">Create Server</Button>
        </PageContentBlock>
    );
};
```

Comment: `Eggs.data !== 'undefined'` this is comparing to a string 'undefined'. What you want is `Eggs.data !== undefined` or `if (!Eggs.data)` or `typeof Eggs.data !== 'undefined'`

Comment: @KevinAmiranoff nice catch. Pretty subtle actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the issue is here:

```
Eggs.data !== 'undefined'
```

this is comparing to a string 'undefined'.

What you want is `Eggs.data !== undefined` or `!Eggs.data` or `typeof Eggs.data !== 'undefined'`

Also, you have some TypeScript issues I believe,
if you do:

```
setEggs({ data });
```

Then you should initialize Eggs like this

```
    const [Eggs, setEggs] = useState<{data: EggsPlace[]}>({data: []});
```

That would also make sure your initialise data with an empty array. Although, it would still break if `data` in `setEggs({ data });` is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the `Eggs.data` try:

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Eggs.data))`

makes a deep copy of the array

Comment: And... how will that fix his problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found why it didn't work it was just I was using 'undefined' instead of undefined.
Thank you all!